# How to draw an angle arc between line segments in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

*Is it possible to use ggplot2 (or plotnine or other grammar of graphics packages) to draw an angle arc between two straight line segments as shown below?*

(ignore the circle etc.)

[image]

I know that this can be done with graphics programs such as Geogebra. But I am interested in drawing the angle mark (and label) *programmatically* in Jupyter.

(By the way, is there a word for this "angle arc"? I don't know how to call it, and just used "angle arc".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For R, there is the `ggforce` package that extends ggplot2 and defines a `geom_arc()` that comes pretty close. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

start <- c(x = 0, y = 0)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = start[c("x", "x")],
  y = start[c("y", "y")],
  xend = c(1, 4),
  yend = c(5, 1)
)

angles <- with(dat, atan2(xend - x, yend - y))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_segment(aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_arc(aes(x0 = start["x"], y0 = start["y"], r = 1, 
               start = angles[1], end = angles[2])) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: Try `with(dat, atan2(xend - x, yend - y))` instead of the other way round? `geom_arc`'s angles start from vertical axis.

Comment: Great that works very well. Thanks for your comment :) I've adapted the answer to include your comment.